# if uninstall.exe exists run Uninstall step else jump to Install vNext build task

Tags: tfs, build, conditional-statements, task, vnext

I have a release TFS build which has uninstall and install step of an application in my agent folder for further testing.
Unfortunately, when it happens to be fresh install in the agent directory it fails with error "Uninstall' is not recognized as an internal or external command".

In this case, I want to run a script in the batch or command line task to check if uninstall.exe is present before running the Uninstall task. Is there any way where I can call Uninstall or Install step according to the If condition in my script?

for an example 
if exist "C:\Program Files\Altiris\Altiris Agent\AexAgentUtil.exe" goto task1 else task2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it with a batch script or command line, use PowerShell; that's what PowerShell was designed for.

```
if (Test-Path 'C:\Program Files\Altiris\Altiris Agent\AexAgentUtil.exe') {
   # do something
}
else {
   # do something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. But I also wanted to check if we have pre-defined variables in TFS vNext Build tasks so that i can do something as follows: if (Test-Path 'C:\Program Files\Altiris\Altiris Agent\AexAgentUtil.exe') {
   # run uninstall vnext task
}
else {
   # run install vnext  task
}

Comment: @rk30 Variables can be accessed in your script. Refer to the documentation.